# Why am I getting and "Image not found" error when converting pdf to html?

Tags: pdf-to-html

I am using pdftohtml tool to convert pdfs to html using the following command:
**`pdftohtml -s -c SOURCE_FILE_NAME`**

which results in the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openjpeg/lib/libopenjpeg.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/pdftohtml
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I haven't managed to find outwhy this is happening thus far. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: It may you do not have this library `libopenjpeg.5.dylib` or the executable file have no reference to it.

Comment: Aye. It seems that my library is an older version. Don't suppose you know  which packages include this on OSX?

Comment: try `ldd /usr/local/bin/pdftohtml` to see it refers to which libraries and **you have it or not**

Comment: **"otool -L"** instead of **ldd** on osx.
In anycase I got this: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/pT35bYGBcWNId5Ec79TzZg

Comment: this line: `/usr/local/opt/openjpeg/lib/libopenjpeg.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 1.5.2)` I think your version of this, is old. So find ti and install the latest version